# Private etcd cluster using tokens

Tags: etcd

I'm trying to set up an embedded etcd cluster on a bunch of machines that I'm keeping track of (so I always have the list of machine IPs), and there will always be at least one machine with a known static IP that's always in the cluster.

I'd like to set it up so any machine that has a secret token can join this cluster, assuming I boostrap it with the token and one or more current cluster member IP addresses.

The only options that seem relevant are the `initial-cluster` and `initial-cluster-token`, but I can't make out where to set up the bootstrap servers.

Or does it make sense to just trust the (or a private) discovery service for this? Does the discovery service automatically scale up to member past the initial size, and does it work well for long lived clusters that have a lot of servers leaving joining over months or years?